# Problems getting agregate functions' values with RadTreeListView's column.getaggregateresults()

Tags: silverlight, telerik, aggregate-functions, radtreelist

I am using a Count AggregateFunction and I would like to access it's value from the code behind. This task can be managed using the function `getaggregateresults(QueryableCollectionViewGroup group)` but I am having problems accessing the `QueryableCollectionViewGroup` object, because it's constructor is protected.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
   <GridViewDataColumn  UniqueName="NameHeader">                   
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                    <telerik:CountFunction Caption="Count: " />
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
    </GridViewDataColumn>`
```

The function call would be laike this:

`this.RadTreeListView.Columns["NameHeader"].GetAggregateResults(QUERYABLEGROUP).ElementAt(0).FormattedValue;`

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to retrieve the answer executing this function when the RadTreeListView.DataLoaded event occurs:

```
    void UnselectedItemsDataGrid_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        var s = (RadTreeListView)sender;
        s.CalculateAggregates();
        AggregateResult result = s.AggregateResults[0];
    }
```

The `RadTreeListView` only has the Count aggregate function, so it always be at index 0. The result is wrapped on the `AggregateResult`. This code is an example, however it lights the path to a solution.

I hope this answer will be able to help if anyone has the same problem.